# Validation on partial view is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am creating simple mvc application using c#.

when I use Partial view to get the input the validation is not triggered.I have done the validation using data annotation .And another thing I am not using any form element in the partial view

What is the solution for the Kindly give the suggestion to this

Comment: Hello @Sri, welcome to the stackoverflow. Kindly provide more context related with your problem, if necessary provide codebase.

Comment: That would be because your code is wrong (are you wanting us to guess what that is)

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume you a building a form you would like to submit.

First of all, you will suggest to you use EditorTemplates and not partial views. But this is just a tip.

Here is an example of loading partial view and resetting validation

```
$("#btnNewOrderLine").click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    (<any>$('#modalEditOrderLine')).modal('show');
    var orderId = $("#OrderID").val();
    $('#modalOrderLineBody').load("/ExactSalesOrders/PartialOrderLineDetail/", { orderLineId: "new", orderId: orderId },
        () => {
            $('#formOLDetail').removeData('validator');
            $('#formOLDetail').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
            $("#formOLDetail").each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); }); //enable to display the error messages
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formOLDetail");
        }
    );

});
```

Edit: you don't need to add any scripts to the end of the partialview page

Comment: did you try adding them without @section Scripts.

Comment: Yes I added just you specified

Comment: What I meant is Without @section Scripts{ }. So, just   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Comment: Edited my answer giving you example of TS code which actually uses partial view and resets validation for partial view. This is what you actually need

Comment: I am calling partial view using ajax post method and in my partial view i don't haveany form element

Comment: Look at the example code I have given you. It is Ajax post request ($(...).load(url...), on success of the post the validation is reset by removing validators for the Main Form and after that assigning it back again. So what you have to do is give ID to the main form, and on success of your ajax post method you reset validation as shown above

Answer (score 0):

See your ViewModal should contain all the **Properties** including the properties you are showing in Partial View. And you should include **Data Annotation** attribute to the required properties.
For Example:

```
public class myViewModal
{
 [Required]
 public int Id{get;set;}
 [Required]
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public string Desc{get;set;}

 //These two properties are for partial view
 [Required]
 public string DOB{get;set;}
 [Required]
 public string AnyOtherField{get;set;}
 }
```

You should reference this model in your main view

```
@model MyProject.Model.myViewModal
```

Then **Inside BeginForm or Form Tag** in main view, you need to render the partial view to work validation.

```
@HTML.Beginform()
{
 // My main View HTML goes here
 // Here call the partial view
}
```

Comment: I am calling partial view using ajax using jquery

Comment: No problem. U can call/load the partial using anything, but it should be render inside the main @HTML.Beginform to work the Data annotation validation. Other wise u need to do validation by using jquery.